# Download file with resteasy

Tags: file, resteasy

I have a rest app with resteasy, which creates files and stores them and return the path, so I can see the name in the screen. The problem: When I want to download the file, I create the url with "app url" + "file path" but that doesn't work. The message is:
Could not find resource for relative : /publications_report_486.doc of full path:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/SIISA-Rest-0.6/publications_report_486.doc`

In this example, I store the file in the app's root, so I just have to add the filename to the url.

I think resteasy is trying to find that url within their resources(services) and it doesn't find the path, so it doesn't access to the file, it just search the services.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to return the file from within Resteasy - I've been looking for that myself which is how I stumbled across this, but you could probably deal with this particular problem by tweaking the your web.xml so that it doesn't include the location where you store your files in the servlet-mapping to Resteasy. You may want to have a look at the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469738/692560).